# 6 month rolling average

Tags: google-sheets, moving-average

In google sheets I have data for monthly values going across the sheet -

```
100,345,34,54,34,67,56,89,555
```

I need to add a row underneath this data to show a 6 month rolling average figure.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsisAyzLzDs - upload an Excel to Googlesheets - it should convert anything if the syntax is difference

Answer (score 0):

Did you want something like this?

[image: Screenshot]

Start in F2 with `=AVERAGE(A1:F1)` and drag or copy across.